# NodeJS JSON is local when it should be global

Tags: json, node.js, express, ejs

I'm working with nodeJS express ejs. I have a problem with my JSON which is not populated with data before rendering my ejs file.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) { 
    fs.readFile('somepath', 'utf8', function(errRead, data) { 
        var obj;
        if(errRead) { 
            obj = {loaded : false};
        } else {
            var nbCam = 0;
            fs.readFile('somepath', 'utf8', function(errRead, data) {
                if(errRead) throw errRead; 
                for(var i in JSON.parse(data).currentAcquisitionSet) {
                    ++nbCam;
                }
                obj = {loaded : nbCam, images : JSON.parse(data).images};
            });
        }
        console.log(obj); // why is it undefined here?
        res.render('a.ejs', obj);});
    });
});
```

It looks like my obj is a local variable but I can't understand why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `callback` for `fs.readFile` is invoked *after* you log `obj` as [`fs.readFile`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback) is *asynchronous*

If you did want to read the data in a *synchronous* fashion, you can use [`fs.readFileSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options), or change the render to within the callback

```
app.get('/', function(req, res, next) { 
    fs.readFile('somepath', 'utf8', function(errRead, data) { 
        var obj;
        if(errRead) { 
            obj = {loaded : false};
            res.render('a.ejs', obj);
            return;
        } 
        fs.readFile('somepath', 'utf8', function(errRead, data) {
            if(errRead) {
                return next(errRead);
            }
            var nbCam = 0;
            for(var i in JSON.parse(data).currentAcquisitionSet) {
                ++nbCam;
            }
            obj = {loaded : nbCam, images : JSON.parse(data).images};
            console.log(obj);
            res.render('a.ejs', obj);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I completely forgot that asynchronous part.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to read a json file from disk, you can just require it:

```
var data = require('somepath');
```

This will synchronously load the file one time when your app first calls it, then store it in the npm cache.

I'd probably call that at the top of a file with the other require statements rather than inside a route handler, but that's my preference.